# how to return items in a dynamodb on aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

So, I have a DynamoDB table `Users` and I want to return all the contents of this table. Or maybe even some.

I tried

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name Users
```

and it says I have to specify `key-condition` or `key-condition-expression`, so I added the following:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name Users --key-condition-expression Username = "test"
```

and it returns an error message `" Unknown options: test "`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you want to dump the whole table, just use

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name Users
```

Comment: It appears that, for all but the smallest of tables, this yields the error, "An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the Scan operation (reached max retries: 2): The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API."

Comment: Apparently to fix this error, you can change the read-write capacity mode of the table from provisioned to on-demand.

Answer (score 50):

Try this format:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name Users --key '{"Username": {"S": "test"}}'
```

Comment: If you're getting a `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema` error when running this, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757872/the-provided-key-element-does-not-match-the-schema-error-when-getting-an-item).

Comment: Unknown options: test}}', {S:

Answer (score 18):

Since the question is about using the `query` operation, here it goes.

As the [AWS cli documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-dynamodb.html) explains, you should separate the attribute values from the condition, by using the `--expression-attribute-values` parameter:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name Users 
    --key-condition-expression "Username = :v1" 
    --expression-attribute-values "{ \":v1\" : { \"S\" : \"test\" } }"
```

Additionally, you may combine more attributes in the filter (in my case I have a Datetime sort key I want to filter by):

```
aws dynamodb query 
  --table-name Users
  --key-condition-expression "Username = :v1 AND #Datetime BETWEEN :v2 AND :v3" 
  --expression-attribute-names "{ \"#Datetime\": \"Datetime\" }" 
  --expression-attribute-values "{ \":v1\" : { \"S\" : \"test\" }, \":v2\" : { \"S\" : \"2019-06-06\" }, \":v3\" : { \"S\" : \"2019-06-07\" } }"
```

Here the `#Datetime` mapping is done through the `--expression-attribute-names` parameter, because `Datetime` is a reserved keyword, so I cannot use it inside the key condition expression.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was forgot to escape the query params :)

Comment: The first query here yields the error, "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: id".

Comment: Hey @kloddant, I think you're trying to run a query using a condition that does not include your primary key (`id`). Without knowing how your query looks like, I guess you need to add a secondary index with the attributes you are querying. Or, you may run a `Scan` instead of a `Query`. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: @SebaGra Thanks, yup, had to run a scan instead.

Comment: Please @SebaGra correct your syntax mistake: "by using the --expression-atribute-values" an additional t is needed on the attribute

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you are not passing "key"(hash or hash/range) properly

create a file containing your keys:
test.json

```
{
    "userName": {"S": "abc"},
    "anyRangeKey": {"S": "xyz"}  //optional
}
```

Run

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name users --key file://test.json
```

refer:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name ProductCatalog --key "{""Id"":{""N"":""205""}}" --no-verify-ssl
```